# Adding ESX host through VPN based IP

Tags: vpn, ip, vmware-esx, vmware-vcenter

We have many esx host in branch. To manage them, we using vsphere client for each of them. Brach office and head office is connected with VPN based IP. For each branch is connected with 1 Mbps banwidth to head office.
In our head office, we have about 5 esx host managed with one vcenter management. I want to add esx host which is located at the branch to our vcenter server at head office.
Is there any restriction for adding esx host through VPN tunnel?
I am afraid after we add esx host, we will have quality of VPN IP is declining.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That should work fine as long as there are no firewall rules that block the management traffic.

Whether or not your "VPN quality" declines is completely dependent on the bandwidth currently available through the VPN and how much of that bandwidth is being used. That said, there's typically not a whole lot of traffic between ESXi servers and their vCenter server.

Comment: Thank you @ErikA. Why I ask this, because our distributor once told us not to pool  all esx host from our branch to vcenter server at head office. They said it will consume much VPN banwidth of each branch.

Comment: Well, as I said, this is all completely dependent on the resources you have available. There's no harm in trying it out to see how it works. If it causes problems, then just remove that ESXi host from the vCenter org.

Answer (score 1):

We do exactly this kind of thing for lots of remote ESXi boxes, so long as you've got the right ports open then you'll have no issue whatsoever.

Answer (score 0):

It should work without problems, but(!):

1. Guest console view will be considerably slow on 1Mbit line.
2. Be careful to disable any live migration and load balancing features (if vCenter decides it wants to migrate a large machine from your head office, to your branch office over 1MBit line, it will take a lot of time).

Comment: You'd have to be sharing your storage down that line too - which would be a far bigger problem. Also vMotion just won't work on such a slow line, it actually won't pass initial checks.